# Laravel application in NGINX throwing 502 bad gateway

Tags: 16.04, php, nginx

I have configured NGINX to execute my laravel application inside of my FTP directory. However, when I visit my website, I receive a 502 bad gateway.

My configuration looks like so:

```
server {

    server_name exoscape.co.uk;

    root            /home/exoscapeftp/ftp/ExoscapeWebsite/public;

    # Disallow access to hidden files (.htaccess, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    # Some locations will never contain PHP files, handle it in the server
    location ~ ^/(robots.txt|favicon.ico)(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location = /index.php {
        # Disable direct access to the source code of index.php. If you have a
        # Laravel route for '/index.php', copy the @php_router block below.
        return 404;
    }

    location / {
        # Try to serve the static files, otherwise call into PHP
        try_files $uri @php_router;
    }

    location @php_router {
        include fastcgi_params;
        # If you move index.php outside public/, adjust it here.
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exoscape.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/exoscape.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I have ensured I am using the correct PHP version by using `php --ini` which says I am using 7.0. I have ensured the file path is correct. Any help appreciated!

**Update:**

My path to `php7.0-fpm.sock` was incorrect. It was wrapped inside a sub-directory, `php`. This has been replaced now to:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

After clearing my browser cache, reloading the nginx configuration, I still receive the 502 error.

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway indicates a PHP backend issue, are you sure PHP is running where you think it is?  That path for the socket doesn't seem accurate...

Comment: Where should the socket be? @ThomasWard

Comment: Is this a 16.04 box running nginx and PHP from the repos?

Comment: Yeah, used git install on everything, jus can’t get the PHP to work @ThomasWard

Comment: After checking my `/var/run` directory, I saw that `php7.0-fpm.sock` was in a sub directory `php`. After updating this in my server configuration and running `sudo nginx -s reload` I still get the 502 error @ThomasWard

Comment: Clear your browser cache before you say the 502 still happens.  Browsers always cache stupid things like that.

Comment: Yeah, I went to Chrome settings, Advanced > Clear browsing data > Cached images and files from the start of time then reloaded. It still gives me the 502 bad gateway @ThomasWard

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but my nginx version is `1.15.12` @ThomasWard

Comment: After updating the `/index.php` route to see if I could manually access the file to `try_files $uri @php_router;` when I head over to my domain/index.php it downloads the index file :/ @ThomasWard